# AngularJS form validation "required" not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having problem with angular validation.

this one does'nt work...

```
<input type="text" ng-model="text1" name="text1" required>
<span ng-show="text1.$error.required">Please enter something!</span>
```

but this works:

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" ng-model="text1" name="text1" required>
<span ng-show="myform.text1.$error.required">Please enter something!</span>
</form>
```

is it possible to somehow correct the first one without placing it inside a form?

thanks

Comment: *"is it possible to somehow correct the first one without placing it inside a form?"* - No. Well.. It is actually *possible*, but not worth it, believe me, much simpler to do have form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, it is not possible. The [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) is what handles the states of each form element, so you need a reference to it in order to check the validation state.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "ng-form" directive if you really dont want to add a form tag.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-form="myForm">
    <input type="text" required ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username">
    <button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">DO</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

[example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lb32DkXcCpfhVdfKNgBV?p=preview)